# JQuery UI draggable bug

Tags: css, jquery-ui-draggable

```
$(function () {
$(".draggable").draggable({ 
        snap: ".snap",
        revert: true
    });

    });
$(".snap").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) 
    {
        var drag = ui.draggable;
        var drop = $(this);
        $(this).html(drag.html());
        $(this).attr('name', drag.attr('id'));
    }
});
```

});

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yrvUq/1/)

Please find my jsfiddle link above. I found this weird bug which wasn't happening before. when dragging the left hand side divs for the first time the divs are snapping of place, then when I have snapped all right hand side divs I can drag and drop as much as I want without this bug happening.

Comment: Define "properly".  We have no idea what you intend for this to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed you have

```
$(".draggable").draggable()(
```

in the fiddle instead of

```
$(".draggable").draggable(
```

That's problem 1 - I couldn't see what was happening in the Fiddle.

Problem 2 is because after the drop the

html is moving into the drop divs
so you'll need to change you css.

try adding  "float: left;" to the snap css

```
.snap{
    width: 146px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```

You'll also need to update your .fixed css to make it appear at the bottom:

```
.fixed{
    width: 450px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float:right;
}
```